# Is `SQLSTATE '23000'` part of a standard?

Tags: postgresql

The following answer uses `SQLSTATE '23000'`.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/130121/50410

Is this something specific for Postgresql or is this part of the SQL standard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL standard defines this SQLSTATE. To quote ISO/IEC 9075-2:2003:

> ## 23 Status codes
>
> ### 23.1 SQLSTATE
>
> The character string value returned in an SQLSTATE parameter comprises a 2-character class value followed by a 3-character subclass value, each with an implementation-defined character set that has a one-octet character encoding form and is restricted to <digit>s and <simple Latin upper case letter>s. Table 32, “SQLSTATE class and subclass values”, specifies the class value for each condition and the subclass value or values for each class value.
>
> [...]
>
> ### Table 32 — SQLSTATE class and subclass values
>
> | Category | Condition | Class | Subcondition | Subclass |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | X | *integrity constraint violation* | 23 | *(no subclass)* | 000 |

Answer (score 2):

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/errcodes-appendix.html)

> All messages emitted by the PostgreSQL server are assigned five-character error codes that follow the SQL standard's conventions for “SQLSTATE” codes.
> ...
> Note that some, but not all, of the error codes produced by PostgreSQL are defined by the SQL standard; some additional error codes for conditions not defined by the standard have been invented or borrowed from other databases.
> ... 
> For each error class there is a “standard” error code having the last three characters 000.

So all codes with `000` at the end, are standard error codes which includes `23000`